# saving a phone number + country code

Tags: android

I want to ask the user for his phone number and for his country code. As some users don't know the code, I thought of making a spinner with all the options so that the user selects from it (for example, for USA it would say +1 -United States). I was wondering if someone already did that and is on the internet, it would save me a lot of time because if not I would have to enter tons of country codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Locale.getISOCountries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getISOCountries%28%29) to obtain a list of all known countries.
Next you could use [PhoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode()](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#getRegionCodeForCountryCode%28int%29) from the [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) project to find the country code of each country.

No need to enter any country codes yourself :)